# Make parent menu link toggle submenu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu which I have working fine but I need a small change and that is I need the parent menu to toggle the submenu, currently if you click the parent menu the submenu appears but I need it so when you click the parent menu again it closes the sub menu.

You can see the menu in action [here](http://foley13.webfactional.com/sotl).

and this is the javascript that is for the menu:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown').css('display', 'none'); // Hide submenus when other submenus are clicked
  $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
  }
});
```

This is the menu html

```
<nav class="main">

    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu One</a>

    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown').css('display', 'none'); // Hide submenus when other submenus are clicked
  $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

With the code below:

```
 $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {

    var $currentDropdown = $(this).next('.dropdown');

    $currentDropdown.siblings('.dropdown').not($currentDropdown).removeClass('toggled');
    $currentDropdown.siblings('.dropdown').not($currentDropdown).hide();

    $currentDropdown.toggleClass('toggled');
    $currentDropdown.toggle();

});
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will be enough.

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPJery)

Comment: That has the toggle effect I want however when you look now [(http://foley13.webfactional.com/sotl)] when you click on each parent menu it just toggles the submenu, I need it so menu one toggles menu 1 submenu and menu two toggles submenu 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplier way :)
Hope you helped

```js
$(".dropdown").css('display', 'none');

$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).next().is(":visible")){
    $(this).next().hide();
  }else{
    $(".dropdown").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><nav class="main">
<nav>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu One</a>

    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu One</a>

    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with Bootstrap:

```
<li class="submenu">

    <i class="la la-user"></i>
    <span> Main menue </span>
    <span class="menu-arrow"></span>

    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="#">sub menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> sub menu 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> sub menu 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```